# How to get ICE candidates to be added in sdp description

Tags: android, webrtc

I'm developing a native android application that uses webrtc, more specifically a DataChannel, to send data to another person. It's working between two android phones, using ICE trickling for this case.

But right now I'm trying to establish a connection between the android phone and a browser (a Chrome instance in my computer, in this case).

The thing is that I'm using a library in js that doesn't handle the message with candidates received through the websocket, it's only working with the **candidates that are already in the sdp of the offer/answer**, if they come in another message, they are discarded (poor implementation, I know). I want to be able to handle this without getting rid of this library, and right now browser to browser it works just fine.

So here's my question: in android I was sending the candidates through websocket as soon as I got them in `onIceCandidate( IceCandidate iceCandidate )`. I changed it, I'm not sending them (commented that code) and I'm delaying the sending of the offer through websocket to happen only after `onIceGatheringChange( PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState )` is returning `COMPLETE`. But even with this waiting, the **sdp description does not contain anything about the ice-candidates**, it's exactly the same as if no candidate was available yet... And there's `a=ice-options:trickle renomination`, which I don't know who is setting this option or if it can be changed.

Is the sdp description supposed to be **changing** after it's creation? I find that it remains the same no matter what, what is set in `onCreateSuccess( SessionDescription sdp )`.

I also tried another thing, to set `iceCandidatePoolSize` to `1` in order to get candidates before the offer creation, but it didn't change a thing.

Am I missing something? Does the sdp change only by waiting for candidates really? Or do I need to disable the trickle somehow? I wasn't able to find this info.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a late reply, but I'll answer anyway. Recently faced the same problem. It is solved in this way:
in  createLocalPeerConnection, you need to add a method:

```
  @Override
        public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {
            super.onIceGatheringChange(iceGatheringState);
            if(iceGatheringState == PeerConnection.IceGatheringState.COMPLETE) {
                createLoclOffer(sdpConstraints);
            }
        }
```

With a condition, you check the status of the collection of candidates and then call the sdp submit method.

Value:

**new**
The peer connection was just created and hasn't done any networking yet.

**gathering**
The ICE agent is in the process of gathering candidates for the connection.

**complete**
The ICE agent has finished gathering candidates. If something happens that requires collecting new candidates, such as a new interface being added or the addition of a new ICE server, the state will revert to gathering to gather those candidates.

Please note that in order to collect ice candidates, an already formed sdp is required.

I found another way to solve the problem. If you wait for the COMPLETE status of the collection of ice candidates, then it takes a very long time. For this reason, you can set a time counter (2 seconds will be enough), after the time has elapsed, call the method with a suggestion.

```
 new CountDownTimer(2000, 1000) {

        
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }
        
        public void onFinish() {
            createLoclOffer(sdpConstraints);
        }
    }
            .start();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how are you gathering those candidates before creating the offer (`peerConnection.createOffer()`)? What do you mean by "an already formed sdp is required"? I wasn't able to get candidates before creating the offer.

Comment: That's it! You cannot receive candidates before creating an offer. Therefore, create a proposal before collecting ice candidates. After that, collect the candidates and call again the method where the offer was made.

Comment: The option is certainly not beautiful, but this is all that I could think of now.)

Comment: This worked for me. Basically, createOffer, then setLocalDescription, then wait for ICE candidates (using whatever candidates have been received after 1 second even if not complete), then createOffer() and setLocalDescription AGAIN, then finally sending the offer to the remote side.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the code you need: https://github.com/x186k/whip-whap-js/blob/main/whip-whap-js.js#L40

The order is: createOffer, setLocalDescription, wait till ICE gathering state is completed, grab RTCPeerConnection's localDescription - it will include all the ICE candidates. There's no need to do createOffer/setLocalDescription again